# Mysql syntax error on IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I try get vacancies per course, cause have limited vacancies per course;

So a need return:

Course 1 - No vacancies
Course 2 - 2 vacancies

```
SELECT
                        curs.CURSO_ID,
                        curs.CURSO_NOME,
                        curs.CURSO_DATA_INICIO,
                        curs.CURSO_DATA_FIM,
                        curs.CURSO_DESCRICAO,
                        curs.CURSO_LINK,
                        cate.CAT_CUR_ID,
                        cate.CAT_CUR_DESCRICAO,
                        curs.CURSO_VAGAS,

                        (
                            SELECT COUNT(sol.SOLI_ID)
                            FROM 
                            solicitacao AS sol
                            WHERE 
                            sol.SOLI_FK_CURSO_ID = curs.CURSO_ID 
                        ) AS pedido,

                    IF (
                         curs.CURSO_VAGAS > pedido THEN (curs.CURSO_VAGAS - pedido) ELSE 0
                       ) AS totalVagas


                     /** CASE WHEN (curs.CURSO_VAGAS > pedido) THEN (curs.CURSO_VAGAS - pedido) ELSE 0 END AS totalVagas **/

                      FROM 
                        curso AS curs

                      LEFT JOIN curso_categoria AS cate ON cate.CAT_CUR_ID = curs.CURSO_FK_CATEGORIA_ID

                      ORDER BY
                        CURSO_DATA_INICIO ASC
```

Thanks for help

Comment: If i try:
SELECT
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(sol.SOLI_ID)
                                FROM 
                                solicitacao AS sol
                                WHERE 
                                sol.SOLI_FK_CURSO_ID = curs.CURSO_ID 
                            ) AS pedido,

                        IF (
                             (curs.CURSO_VAGAS - pedido) > 0,(curs.CURSO_VAGAS - pedido),0
                           ) AS totalVagas

Return: Unknown column 'pedido' in 'filed list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `IF` syntax:

```
 IF (curs.CURSO_VAGAS > (
    SELECT COUNT(sol.SOLI_ID) 
    FROM solicitacao AS sol
    WHERE 
    sol.SOLI_FK_CURSO_ID = curs.CURSO_ID
 ), (curs.CURSO_VAGAS - (
    SELECT COUNT(sol.SOLI_ID) 
    FROM solicitacao AS sol
    WHERE 
    sol.SOLI_FK_CURSO_ID = curs.CURSO_ID
 )), 0) AS totalVagas
```

You can use alias name only in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses

Comment: Thanks for help! Solution ok

Comment: Please try the second solution an tell me if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try another solution:

```
IF (curs.CURSO_VAGAS > (SELECT pedido), (curs.CURSO_VAGAS - (SELECT pedido )), 0) AS totalVagas
```